# Bonobo git: virtualPath is null

Tags: git, iis, bonobo

I have downloaded Bonobo Git server and trying to host it in my Windows server 2016 VM with iis.

I have followed all the steps from the installation manual and receive following error:

> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: virtualPath]
>      System.Web.VirtualPath.Create(String virtualPath, VirtualPathOptions options) +12167132
>      Bonobo.Git.Server.MvcApplication.GetLogFileNameFormat() +48
>      Bonobo.Git.Server.MvcApplication.ConfigureLogging() +119
>      Bonobo.Git.Server.MvcApplication.Application_Start() +21
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: virtualPath]
>      System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +540
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +186
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>      System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +402
>      System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +343
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: virtualPath]
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +539
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +125
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +731

This seems to come from the Bonobo code so i cannot debug this. Also no other info about this error found.

Any clues on what i could have configured wrong since i think the Bonobo project should work ..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have something like

```
    <add key="LogDirectory" value="~\App_Data\Logs" />
```

In the `appsettings` section of your `web.config` file.

Out of interest, did you upgrade from a previous version?